# Make apache 2 server show loading page on all endpoints until an external service is ready to accept connection

Tags: apache2

I have a front end project running hosted with apache2. This project leverages api hosted on localhost at port 3000. The catch is the external service needs about 10 - 15 minutes to start up. So i want to just show `loading.html` until localhost:3000 is ready to accept connects. ** note i want all endpoint to show the loading page since all pages requires the api. What is the best way to go about this?

I tried to set this up using proxy page and show loading page if that endpoint is not responding. But this waits for the request to time out and is only bound to a single endpoint mentioned in the proxy pass.